# Pivot Table not displaying value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pivot table in which all values are showing with the exception of my last field, it simply counts as '1' and sums as '0'. Its a formulated cell in which the value returns 1:(c3/j3+o3). This value doesn't appear in my values list however it will appear when i drag it over to my row labels. I've tried looking at the formatting of the cell, data validation and text to columns etc but i do not believe it would be that when the value is shown when inputted into row labels.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify, in the source data does this column contain numbers or text?

Comment: Its numbers, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution via adding a calculated field, using the same formula from the raw data and that seemingly did the trick.